# How do I fix my WordPress pages not displaying correctly?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have a WordPress site where all the parent pages only show the homepage, even if you try to preview them from the backend, but the children pages show correctly.

You can see the site here: http://dev1.marketsonline.co.za/khulisa/

I've never had this problem before, and it's baffling me.

How do I fix this?

**UPDATE**

Here is the code in my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /khulisa/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /khulisa/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to flush your permalink cache.

Go into Settings -> permalink and change the permalink structure for one time. Then you save it. Now your permalink cache is flushed.

Another solutions could be that you have a redirect plugin? Or some redirects in your .htaccess file?

Comment: Tried your first suggestion multiple times with no luck, if I set my permalinks to "Default" everything works fine. Regarding the .htaccess file, I've added nothing extra in there, it's all wordpress generated.

Comment: Then change your theme for one time and try it again.

Comment: I activated Twenty Fifteen and had the same problem, main pages only work with default permalinks (even flushed the permalinks).

Comment: Can you edit your question and input your .htaccess file? And take a look into phpinfo(); Maybe the redirect modul of your apache is deactivated.

Comment: Updated my question. The rewrite rule is definitely enabled on the dev1.marketsonline.co.za server. I have other WordPress sites on multiple sub directories and they work perfectly.

Comment: I am not sure but try to include this in top of your .htaccess file: 
Options +FollowSymlinks

Comment: Just added it, nothing changed :(

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem. I disabled all my plugins, change my theme to one of the default ones, and flushed my permalinks. After doing those 3 things all my pages were working 100%

**Update**

So even though the above worked, it didn't actually fix the initial problem. I found the problem, which was with my custom taxonomy with the name "year", I'm assuming WordPress has a predefined taxonomy with that exact name which caused some conflict. I just renamed my custom taxonomy and everything was really working 100%